# REST API and User Information List Permissions and Breeze.js

Tags: rest, listdata.svc, user-information-list

Users who are not site collection admins can read from the User Information List without any issues when using `http://server.domain.com/_vti_bin_/ListData.svc/UserInformationList` but these users get a 404 error when accessing it via `http://server.domain.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('User Information List')`. Site collection admins do not receive a 404 error. Would anyone have any idea why this might be and if there is a work around for this specific end point?

I know that I could use `_api/web/siteusers` but this is not really preferable when using Breeze.js's SharePoint adapter as it is apparently expecting me to specify the title of a list and I am trying to be consistent in my data context.

**EDIT:** Actually the `siteusers` end point does not provide the same data, it really only has a subset. What I have done as a work around was modify my `datacontext` object to use `$http` and `ListData.svc` rather than using breeze. Since I am never modifying the user data it's ultimately not that big of a deal but I'd still like to figure out a better way to do this as `ListData.svc` is deprecated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose `_vti_bin/ListData.svc` and `_vti_bin/client.svc` (`_api`) endpoints have different logic for permission checks.

I can reproduce your problem, while logged as a site admin I can access the list, but not as a normal user:

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('User Information List')
```

What I also have found in the result, is a new (third) link to that hidden list:

```
_api/web/SiteUserInfoList/
```

With this link non-site-admins can access the same information. I know you wanted a unified access to that list for you breeze.js sp adapter. But perhaps, this could be a workaround without needing to go back to the old ListData.svc endpoint.

Comment: That's very helpful, thank you! I'm going to see if I can contact Andrew Connell and the Breeze team. Maybe I can build something specific for the breeze Sp adapter to get user details. If I end up needing to do this I will add details about that to your answer and then select it. Thanks again!