# SharePoint online REST: Get users profile properties

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, rest

I'm looking for some help with a REST call I'm attempting to make in SharePoint Online.

I'm doing an add-in that gives me the name, birhday and photo property of all user in user profiles

[image]

I tried with this code

```
 var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;
    Console.log(siteUrl);
    $.ajax({
        url: siteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
```

but I only get current user profile properties, what I need is all user profiles properties for all users, how can i achieve that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: all users of the site or on the tenant level? here is a link to a similar question http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/148313/how-to-get-all-properties-of-all-users-in-sharepoint-2013-rest-api

Comment: Is below given solutions works for you?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Still this no API for retrieving all user profiles from SharePoint Online**

You can get current user's profile

```
_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties
```

Or a particular user's profile by login name

```
/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='i:0%23.f|membership|xx@siteurl.onmicrosoft.com'
```

**BUT** You can get available user profiles in a site

```
/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/UserInformationList
```

Comment: How about `SP.UserProfiles.js`? Yes I know OP specifically say REST, but this should actually work, also for apps (which is not so easy with `_vti_bin`).

Comment: You can get the user information from **UserInformationList** using **SP.UserProfiles.js**. But if you want to get users using the tanent than there is no option.

Comment: thanks for the replays, with /_vti_bin/ListData.svc/UserInformationList i get Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) i used it like that, var url = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/UserInformationList"; 

is it wrong?

Comment: It is used to get the user's information from SharePoint's default (hidden) list called **UserInforamtion**.

Comment: I gave this as another option but you need users from tanent & it is not possible to get all user's all information from tanent using REST. :)

Comment: okay, thanks man, so, what do you recommend to me to do to achieve it? get all user's all information from users profile, using other method or strategy.

Comment: If that is the case than you can get your answer from here...http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/123166/rest-api-and-user-information-list-permissions-and-breeze-js

Comment: You can refer this as well...http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/154566/call-entire-user-information-list-from-rest-api

Comment: So, there is and option to get the user profiles from the tenant? CSOM, JSOM?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no option for SharePoint Online.

Comment: Is given solutions works for you? @Emmanuel Villegas

Comment: @Hardik We have the birthday but when I get the User Information List fron this link http://SiteURL/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/UserInformationList the Birthday  is null <d:DateOfBirth m:type="Edm.DateTime" m:null="true" />

Comment: Does this work for external or guess users in SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 2):

you can use SPFx People Picker (version 11+) which was released recently at https://sharepoint.github.io/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/controls/PeoplePicker/ .

Basically, this control will allow you to pick any users in all trusted domains in SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 1):

URL:

```
http://SiteURL/_api/Web/lists/getbytitle('User Information List')/Items
```

Headers:

```
Accept: application/json; odata=verbose
Content-Type: application/json; odata=verbose
```

Answer (score 0):

install pnpjs (https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/)

npm i @pnp/pnpjs

```
import { sp } from "@pnp/pnpjs";
    import { SearchQueryInit } from "@pnp/sp/search";
    
        public async getSearchResults(startRow, rowLimit): Promise<[]> {
                let allResults: any = [];
                let queryParams: any = this._getQueryParams(
                    startRow,
                    rowLimit
                );
                queryParams.Timeout = 60000;
                const results = await (sp as any).search(queryParams);
                allResults.data = results.PrimarySearchResults;
                allResults.totalRows = results.TotalRows;
                return allResults;
            }
            private _getQueryParams(
                startRow: number,
                rowLimit: number
            ) {
                let queryParams: SearchQueryInit = {
                    RowLimit: rowLimit,
                    Querytext: "*",
                    SelectProperties: ["AccountName"],
                    StartRow: startRow,
                    SourceId: "b09a7990-05ea-4af9-81ef-edfab16c4e31",
                    TrimDuplicates: false,
                };
                return queryParams;
            }
         this.getSearchResults(0, 50)
```