# Can I get SharePoint Online user information by user's FirstName and LastName using REST API?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, user-profile-property, sharepoint-rest-api

I am having 2 Single Line Of Text column for FirstName and LastName.

Now I want to get SharePoint Online users with given FirstName and LastName.

Is it possible using JavaScript REST API?

Any suggestion welcomed.

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/180989/sharepoint-online-rest-get-users-profile-properties

Comment: You will get it from my own answer here...https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/180989/sharepoint-online-rest-get-users-profile-properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per comments by [InnovaITve Solutions](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/66704/innovaitve-solutions) and [Hardik](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/41016/hardik), I got solution.

Here is [source](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/180997/30145)

What I did is, I used following URL to make my REST Call

```
SiteUrl/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/UserInformationList?$filter = ((FirstName eq 'MyFirstName') and (LastName eq 'MyLastName'))
```

It returned me all the information I need.